# Execução sequencial em Javascript ou AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, método

Eu estou criando um controller pra uma plicação AngularJs, neste controller eu terei 3 métodos que devem ser executados em sequencia.

EXEMPLO:

```
$scope.albums = [];
$scope.photos = [];

//Metodo que vai setar o array de albums e chamar a função para buscar as fotos de cada album.
function getAlbums() {
    var album = null;
    resource = $resource(url_albums);
    resource.get().$promise.then(function(response) {
        $scope.albums = response.photosets.photoset;
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.albums.length; i++) {
            album = $scope.albums[i];
            getPhotosFromAlbum(album.id);
            //vou pegar a primeira foto e colocar a url dela no album.
        }
    }, function(promise) {
        alert("Ops parece que um erro inesperado ocorreu o_0!");
        console.log(promise);
    });
}

//Seta o array de photos e chama método ara adicionar URL em cada foto.
function getPhotosFromAlbum(album_id) {
    var photos = [];
    url_photos = url_photos.replace('{album_id}', album_id);
    resource = $resource(url_photos);
    resource.get().$promise.then(function(response) {
        $scope.photos = response.photoset.photo;
        addPhotoUrl();
    }, function(promise) {
        alert("Ops parece que um erro inesperado ocorreu o_0!");
        console.log(promise);
    });
}

//Adiciona a url no Json da photo e devolve para o array na mesma posição que estava.
function addPhotoUrl() {
    var photo = null;
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.photos.length; i++) {
        photo = $scope.photos[i];
        photo = Object.defineProperty(photo, 'photo_url:', {
            value: 'http://farm' +
                photo.farm +
                '.staticflickr.com/' +
                photo.server +
                '/' +
                photo.id +
                '_' +
                photo.secret +
                '_b.jpg'
        });
        $scope.photos[i] = photo;
    }
}
```

Eu preciso que esses caras sejam executados em sequencia, executando hoje isso ai vira um banzé quando coloco os console.log() para ver o que esta acontecendo. Preciso de uma forma de fazer isso dar certo, depois de executar o método getPhotosFromAlbum eu vou pegar a primeira photo do array $scope.photos e colocar a url dela no album, só que, depois de executado o metodo getPhotosFromAlbum o array de photos está vazio sendo que ele foi setado nesses metodos.

Espero que não tenha ficado muito confuso, se algum puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Como você utiliza uma requisição para o servidor, automaticamente suas chamadas do `console.log` ficarão misturadas. Mas isso não é necessariamente errado, já que o `Javascript` tem natureza assíncrona. O seu erro está em usar a variável `$scope.photos` em todas as interações. Se você alterá-la para uma matriz seu código irá funcionar:

Na função `getPhotosFromAlbum`:

```
$scope.photos[album_id] = response.photoset.photo;
```

Adicione o parâmetro `album_id` na função `addPhotoUrl`:

```
function addPhotoUrl(album_id) { ...
```

E altere as seguintes linhas:

```
for (i = 0; i < $scope.photos[album_id].length; i++) {
    photo = $scope.photos[album_id][i];
    ...
    $scope.photos[album_id][i] = photo;
```